# Any way to save a row in an excel macro for future usage?

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I'm building a macro to split a long table into multiple smalls tables, and I'd like to have the header saved in a variable to be able to quickly paste it on top of  the smalls table.

I made a macro to do the first one (quite simple)

```
Sheets("Feuil1").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PageImpression").Select
Rows("2:2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

How can I keep my `Selection.Copy` in a variable and how do I paste it when I need to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is to store the row into a variable. Then call that variable when you need it. Also, no need for copy / paste and select and all that :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim myHeader as Variant

myHeader = Sheets("Feuil1").Rows(2)

Sheets("PageImpression").Rows(2) = myHeader
```

**Update**

To use with a `Range` Object, do the following:

```
Dim myHeader As Range

Set myHeader = Sheets(1).Rows(2)

Sheets(2).Rows(2).Value = myHeader.Value
```

**Update 2**

The even cleaner (memory + time saving) way to do this would be:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myHeader as Variant (or Range)

With Sheets("Feuil1")

    myHeader = .Range(.Range("A1"),.Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xltoLeft).Column))
    'for variable type Range, add "Set =" in front of line above

End With

Sheets("PageImpression").Range("A2") = myHeader
'For Range Sheets("PageImpression").Range("A2").Value = myHeader.Value
```

Comment: Wow, so simple... But why don't you use 'Range' for the VarType?

Comment: @Kraz -> Because you need the Variant (or Array may work as well) type to write back to the range. You could adjust it by using ranges, but your code would have to be more explicit. I've edited my answer with how to right with using ranges.

Comment: Would you recommend creating the array based on an array of only the cells in the row with headers in them using a .end statemnt rather than selecting the entire row and creating an array with more than 16,000 indexes, or is the difference negligible?

Comment: @scott - great question! I would recommend creating the array based on only the cells in the row with headers. Anytime you can save memory, you should! I didn't focus on it so much here as I didn't want to bombard the OP with concepts. But since you've asked, I'm updating my post.